# Speed ​up file search

Tags: c#

I want to change the conversion from `List<string>` to the `StringCollection` type. To make files move faster.

```
try
{
    List<string> Picture = new List<string>();
    List<string> PaThS = new List<string>();
    string[] SVF =  {
                  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),  
                  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
                    };
    foreach (var paths in SVF)
                PaThS.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(paths));

    foreach (var e in PaThS)
                Picture.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(e, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
catch{}
}
```

Actually by subject. Modify the StringCollection

Comment: You didn't learn anything from your last closed question. Have you actually read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) I strongly doubt it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Does it currently do what you expect it to?

Comment: I wrote in the title that I want to change the conversion from List <string> to the StringCollection type. To make files move faster.

Comment: @ArteS code review is for people to review your code for quality but not to fix your code. If you are having difficulty with the code, then post it on stackoverflow not here.

Comment: Is this code working as intended, @ArteS?

Comment: @Phrancis'DROPTABLEUsers--,YES

Comment: @ArteS _"Modify the StringCollection"_ **Demands** like that never sound very good, neither are well achieved. You should consider to reformulate your question radically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard disk accesses are measured in ms. RAM accesses in ns, i.e. they are roughly one million times faster! This means that `List<string>` manipulations (which happen in RAM) are much much faster than calls to `Directory.GetDirectories` or `Directory.GetFiles` that access the storage (hard disk, usb stick, SSD ...). Replacing `List<string>` by `StringCollection` won't make any difference!

`List<string>` and `StringCollection` both store data in the main memory. They don't move files and they don't search files.

---

It makes no sense to first add data to an array just to copy it to a list afterwards. Add it to the list directly with a collection initializer:

```
var paths = new List<string> {
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
};
```

---

What kind of crazy casing is `PaThS`? The usual C# style for variables is `camelCase`, i.e. the first character is lower case, succeeding words start with an upper-case letter.